# Laravel - Combine Multiple Array By Values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to combine multiple arrays by time values. 
I have an array like this.

```
[
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:" 8",
      id:6,
      a:0.019444444444444
   },
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:" 9",
      id:6,
      a:0.023611111111111
   },
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"10",
      id:6,
      a:0.018055555555556
   },
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"11",
      id:6,
      a:0.025
   },
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"12",
      id:6,
      a:0.0097222222222222
   }
],
[
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:" 8",
      id:7,
      a:0.0013888888888889
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:" 9",
      id:7,
      a:0.015277777777778
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"10",
      id:7,
      a:0.0027777777777778
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"11",
      id:7,
      a:0.0041666666666667
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"12",
      id:7,
      a:0.019444444444444
   }
]
```

I need the combine this 2 array with y values. For example After combine the arrays should be like this.

```
[
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:" 8",
      id:6,
      a:0.019444444444444
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:" 8",
      id:7,
      a:0.0013888888888889
   }
],
[
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"11",
      id:6,
      a:0.025
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"11",
      id:7,
      a:0.0041666666666667
   }
],
[
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"12",
      id:6,
      a:0.0097222222222222
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"12",
      id:7,
      a:0.019444444444444
   }
],
[
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:" 9",
      id:6,
      a:0.023611111111111
   },
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:" 9",
      id:7,
      a:0.015277777777778
   }
],
[
   {
      x:"Kasap",
      y:"10",
      id:7,
      a:0.0027777777777778
   },
   {
      x:"Kasa",
      y:"10",
      id:6,
      a:0.018055555555556
   }
]
```

what should I do for this case ?

Comment: Format your code, add your trial!

Comment: edited already but giving down vote for asking something is not normal

Comment: No its not mine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are tagging this question "Laravel", you could use the excellent [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) class:

```
collect($array)->flatten(1)->groupBy('y')->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I have tested it with this array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "x" => "Kasaa"
    "y" => "8"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "x" => "Pasa"
    "y" => "9"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "x" => "tasa"
    "y" => "8"
  ]
]
```

> EDIT

```
  $array= array_merge($array1, $array2);
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {

        foreach ( $value as $key => $v) {
            if ($key === 'y'){
             $result[$v]='';
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
        if ($value['y'] == key_exists($value['y'],$result)) {
            $result[$value['y']][$k]= $value;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Still Same now just sorting by descending

Answer (score 0):

Try php built in **array_merge_recursive()** function

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
or make your own function (it may be faster)
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
}
$array = my_array_merge($array1, array2);
print_r($array);
```